# how to display the output which has depended on parent and child value

Tags: javascript

I have the input data, which beneficiaryPayId and parentBenePayId has parent children relationship:

```
 var input = {
 "payBeneficiaries": [{
  "beneficiaryPayId": "c946c383-6a64-476a-b903-3bc8baaa716c",
  "parentBenePayId": "",
  "beneficiary": {
    "topId": "06d5e9eb-7110-4c90-aa77-97b3d8ca2c9a",
    "businessId": "15c58e7d-18dd-49e3-ad86-0bf3f6e5013a",
    "businessName": "Royal NNJ p.l.c."
  },
},
{
  "beneficiaryPayId": "b1da8c12-cb0d-4b0e-8a30-75362dbf73b4",
  "parentBenePayId": "c946c383-6a64-476a-b903-3bc8baaa716c",
  "beneficiary": {
    "topId": "d56eebf3-b97b-429c-ae09-e488d85169cf",
    "businessId": "a52b0a2d-532b-4fd1-b667-c25691217e5e",
    "businessName": "Hammes Macejkovic and Steuber"
  },
},
{
  "beneficiaryPayId": "f5f04b9b-5711-44d5-b06e-fb525d269310",
  "parentBenePayId": "c946c383-6a64-476a-b903-3bc8baaa716c",
  "beneficiary": {
    "topId": "96737c75-7a7f-4edc-a6b5-cb3149879a78",
    "businessId": "4e3b061d-5706-45b4-925d-cab675c95d98",
    "businessName": "Torphy-Osinski"
  },
},
{
  "beneficiaryPayId": "2a027e32-ac76-48e4-9ab5-bec130211107",
  "parentBenePayId": "c946c383-6a64-476a-b903-3bc8baaa716c",
  "beneficiary": {
    "topId": "0f9c1849-2c1d-42ae-bdb1-40d83d912171",
    "businessId": "92ea79f3-ed3f-42e1-8f4c-9e1ccb3d746a",
    "businessName": "Schinner Inc"
    },
    },
   {
    "beneficiaryPayId": "d0ec2133-fb2f-4cf2-8d2b-3d8d9eed7d09",
     "parentBenePayId": "f5f04b9b-5711-44d5-b06e-fb525d269310",
    "beneficiary": {
    "topId": "54c30c9f-a792-4659-adfc-b4287994cf1e",
    "businessId": "e6b95c56-ca17-40a4-b5f7-3a0c9fa9b327",
    "businessName": "Ferry-Donnelly"
    },
    },
   {
  "beneficiaryPayId": "e0b87efe-1bd3-4584-b102-2210ab2bd8a7",
  "parentBenePayId": "2a027e32-ac76-48e4-9ab5-bec130211107",
  "beneficiary": {
    "topId": "b934b36a-0ab5-4869-9220-3bfd90bfb956",
    "businessId": "c47836bb-87e2-482b-bbf0-d42073c372c6",
    "businessName": "Lueilwitz-Johns"
    },
   },
   {
   "beneficiaryPayId": "f58d63f6-e823-493a-acf4-226a9c4d21a1",
   "parentBenePayId": "f5f04b9b-5711-44d5-b06e-fb525d269310",
   "beneficiary": {
    "topId": "4e86ab2e-3a2a-4914-a0b3-153439c4013b",
    "businessId": "aead7de0-f2f3-46ce-a013-f83833b9ec0a",
    "businessName": "Ward-Collier"
    },
    },
   {
   "beneficiaryPayId": "17263490-9b2b-4b87-a638-cbdaf0cd9daa",
   "parentBenePayId": "f5f04b9b-5711-44d5-b06e-fb525d269310",
   "beneficiary": {
     "topId": "751b8076-d7ca-4cca-922b-aabcc4b39845",
     "businessId": "6ae1d6e1-9a3b-482b-9c2a-861b3bea0cd4",
     "businessName": "Nikolaus Dickinson and Wiegand"
    },
   },
   {
   "beneficiaryPayId": "71e36088-724f-4075-be14-5fdb37944447",
   "parentBenePayId": "b1da8c12-cb0d-4b0e-8a30-75362dbf73b4",
   "beneficiary": {
    "topId": "a6c67099-9937-4daa-829f-9b91adfea9a1",
    "businessId": "dbbb2e12-e50a-4905-93c1-29768b6ed74d",
    "businessName": "Rath Group"
   },
   },
  {
   "beneficiaryPayId": "d50f34c9-9576-4511-9c49-4fe1fc296a57",
   "parentBenePayId": "b1da8c12-cb0d-4b0e-8a30-75362dbf73b4",
   "beneficiary": {
    "topId": "12e65313-943a-406a-9771-bd8485a35862",
    "businessId": "70d44d44-f7bf-4fd3-a475-378be757d86f",
    "businessName": "MacGyver Inc"
   },
   }
   ] 
   };
```

Output data should be:

```
      [{"orgHierarchy": ["Royal NNJ p.l.c."]
      }, {
      "orgHierarchy": ["Royal NNJ p.l.c.", "Hammes Macejkovic and Steuber"]
      }, {
      "orgHierarchy": ["Royal NNJ p.l.c.", "Torphy-Osinski"]
      }, {
      "orgHierarchy": ["Royal NNJ p.l.c.", "Schinner Inc"]
      }, {
      "orgHierarchy": ["Royal NNJ p.l.c.", "Torphy-Osinski", "Ferry-Donnelly"]
      }, {
      "orgHierarchy": ["Royal NNJ p.l.c.", "Schinner Inc", "Lueilwitz-Johns"]
      }, {
      "orgHierarchy": ["Royal NNJ p.l.c.", "Torphy-Osinski", "Ward-Collier"]
      }, {
      "orgHierarchy": ["Royal NNJ p.l.c.", "Torphy-Osinski", "Nikolaus Dickinson and Wiegand"]
      }, {
     "orgHierarchy": ["Royal NNJ p.l.c.", "Hammes Macejkovic and Steuber", "Rath Group"]
      }, {
     "orgHierarchy": ["Royal NNJ p.l.c.", "Hammes Macejkovic and Steuber", "MacGyver Inc"]
     }]
```

Here is the code I tried to compare with the parent data with child, but the response, which I'm getting(`businessname`) is displayed multiple times and `orgHierarchy` is a hardcoded value.

```
var mainData = input.payBeneficiaries
mainData.map((dta,key) => {
let result = mainData.map((parent) => {
let children = mainData.filter((child) => {
 if (child.beneficiaryPayId=== parent.parentBenePayId) {
  var employees = [];
     var businessName = dta.beneficiary.businessName
       employees.push({
       "orgHierarchy": businessName
     });
   console.log(employees) 
   }
   })
   })
   })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, you could filter `input` values finding `father` object (`"parentBenePayId" === ""`). Then filter `input` again looking for children and the insert values in result array like this:

```js
 var input = {
     "payBeneficiaries": [{
      "beneficiaryPayId": "c946c383-6a64-476a-b903-3bc8baaa716c",
      "parentBenePayId": "",
      "beneficiary": {
        "topId": "06d5e9eb-7110-4c90-aa77-97b3d8ca2c9a",
        "businessId": "15c58e7d-18dd-49e3-ad86-0bf3f6e5013a",
        "businessName": "Royal NNJ p.l.c."
      },
    },
    {
      "beneficiaryPayId": "b1da8c12-cb0d-4b0e-8a30-75362dbf73b4",
      "parentBenePayId": "c946c383-6a64-476a-b903-3bc8baaa716c",
      "beneficiary": {
        "topId": "d56eebf3-b97b-429c-ae09-e488d85169cf",
        "businessId": "a52b0a2d-532b-4fd1-b667-c25691217e5e",
        "businessName": "Hammes Macejkovic and Steuber"
      },
    },
    {
      "beneficiaryPayId": "f5f04b9b-5711-44d5-b06e-fb525d269310",
      "parentBenePayId": "c946c383-6a64-476a-b903-3bc8baaa716c",
      "beneficiary": {
        "topId": "96737c75-7a7f-4edc-a6b5-cb3149879a78",
        "businessId": "4e3b061d-5706-45b4-925d-cab675c95d98",
        "businessName": "Torphy-Osinski"
      },
    },
    {
      "beneficiaryPayId": "2a027e32-ac76-48e4-9ab5-bec130211107",
      "parentBenePayId": "c946c383-6a64-476a-b903-3bc8baaa716c",
      "beneficiary": {
        "topId": "0f9c1849-2c1d-42ae-bdb1-40d83d912171",
        "businessId": "92ea79f3-ed3f-42e1-8f4c-9e1ccb3d746a",
        "businessName": "Schinner Inc"
        },
        },
       {
        "beneficiaryPayId": "d0ec2133-fb2f-4cf2-8d2b-3d8d9eed7d09",
         "parentBenePayId": "f5f04b9b-5711-44d5-b06e-fb525d269310",
        "beneficiary": {
        "topId": "54c30c9f-a792-4659-adfc-b4287994cf1e",
        "businessId": "e6b95c56-ca17-40a4-b5f7-3a0c9fa9b327",
        "businessName": "Ferry-Donnelly"
        },
        },
       {
      "beneficiaryPayId": "e0b87efe-1bd3-4584-b102-2210ab2bd8a7",
      "parentBenePayId": "2a027e32-ac76-48e4-9ab5-bec130211107",
      "beneficiary": {
        "topId": "b934b36a-0ab5-4869-9220-3bfd90bfb956",
        "businessId": "c47836bb-87e2-482b-bbf0-d42073c372c6",
        "businessName": "Lueilwitz-Johns"
        },
       },
       {
       "beneficiaryPayId": "f58d63f6-e823-493a-acf4-226a9c4d21a1",
       "parentBenePayId": "f5f04b9b-5711-44d5-b06e-fb525d269310",
       "beneficiary": {
        "topId": "4e86ab2e-3a2a-4914-a0b3-153439c4013b",
        "businessId": "aead7de0-f2f3-46ce-a013-f83833b9ec0a",
        "businessName": "Ward-Collier"
        },
        },
       {
       "beneficiaryPayId": "17263490-9b2b-4b87-a638-cbdaf0cd9daa",
       "parentBenePayId": "f5f04b9b-5711-44d5-b06e-fb525d269310",
       "beneficiary": {
         "topId": "751b8076-d7ca-4cca-922b-aabcc4b39845",
         "businessId": "6ae1d6e1-9a3b-482b-9c2a-861b3bea0cd4",
         "businessName": "Nikolaus Dickinson and Wiegand"
        },
       },
       {
       "beneficiaryPayId": "71e36088-724f-4075-be14-5fdb37944447",
       "parentBenePayId": "b1da8c12-cb0d-4b0e-8a30-75362dbf73b4",
       "beneficiary": {
        "topId": "a6c67099-9937-4daa-829f-9b91adfea9a1",
        "businessId": "dbbb2e12-e50a-4905-93c1-29768b6ed74d",
        "businessName": "Rath Group"
       },
       },
      {
       "beneficiaryPayId": "d50f34c9-9576-4511-9c49-4fe1fc296a57",
       "parentBenePayId": "b1da8c12-cb0d-4b0e-8a30-75362dbf73b4",
       "beneficiary": {
        "topId": "12e65313-943a-406a-9771-bd8485a35862",
        "businessId": "70d44d44-f7bf-4fd3-a475-378be757d86f",
        "businessName": "MacGyver Inc"
       },
       }
       ] 
       };
       
       let result = [];
       let father = input.payBeneficiaries.filter(el => el.parentBenePayId === "")[0]
       let children = input.payBeneficiaries.filter(el => el.parentBenePayId === father.beneficiaryPayId)
       result.push({orgHierarchy: [father.beneficiary.businessName]})
       children.forEach(child => {
          result.push({orgHierarchy: [father.beneficiary.businessName, child.beneficiary.businessName]})
          // children of child
          let secondGeneration = input.payBeneficiaries.filter(el => el.parentBenePayId === child.beneficiaryPayId)
          if(secondGeneration.length > 0) {
              secondGeneration.forEach(gen => {
                 result.push({orgHierarchy: [father.beneficiary.businessName, child.beneficiary.businessName, gen.beneficiary.businessName]})
              })
          }
       })
       console.log(result)
```

Comment: @Mohan on first implementation I forgot to add also the children of each child ("the second generation"). Now should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `Array.map` and `Array.find` in order to get the desired output.

```js
var input = {payBeneficiaries:[{beneficiaryPayId:'c946c383-6a64-476a-b903-3bc8baaa716c',parentBenePayId:'',beneficiary:{topId:'06d5e9eb-7110-4c90-aa77-97b3d8ca2c9a',businessId:'15c58e7d-18dd-49e3-ad86-0bf3f6e5013a',businessName:'Royal NNJ p.l.c.',},},{beneficiaryPayId:'b1da8c12-cb0d-4b0e-8a30-75362dbf73b4',parentBenePayId:'c946c383-6a64-476a-b903-3bc8baaa716c',beneficiary:{topId:'d56eebf3-b97b-429c-ae09-e488d85169cf',businessId:'a52b0a2d-532b-4fd1-b667-c25691217e5e',businessName:'Hammes Macejkovic and Steuber',},},{beneficiaryPayId:'f5f04b9b-5711-44d5-b06e-fb525d269310',parentBenePayId:'c946c383-6a64-476a-b903-3bc8baaa716c',beneficiary:{topId:'96737c75-7a7f-4edc-a6b5-cb3149879a78',businessId:'4e3b061d-5706-45b4-925d-cab675c95d98',businessName:'Torphy-Osinski',},},{beneficiaryPayId:'2a027e32-ac76-48e4-9ab5-bec130211107',parentBenePayId:'c946c383-6a64-476a-b903-3bc8baaa716c',beneficiary:{topId:'0f9c1849-2c1d-42ae-bdb1-40d83d912171',businessId:'92ea79f3-ed3f-42e1-8f4c-9e1ccb3d746a',businessName:'Schinner Inc',},},{beneficiaryPayId:'d0ec2133-fb2f-4cf2-8d2b-3d8d9eed7d09',parentBenePayId:'f5f04b9b-5711-44d5-b06e-fb525d269310',beneficiary:{topId:'54c30c9f-a792-4659-adfc-b4287994cf1e',businessId:'e6b95c56-ca17-40a4-b5f7-3a0c9fa9b327',businessName:'Ferry-Donnelly',},},{beneficiaryPayId:'e0b87efe-1bd3-4584-b102-2210ab2bd8a7',parentBenePayId:'2a027e32-ac76-48e4-9ab5-bec130211107',beneficiary:{topId:'b934b36a-0ab5-4869-9220-3bfd90bfb956',businessId:'c47836bb-87e2-482b-bbf0-d42073c372c6',businessName:'Lueilwitz-Johns',},},{beneficiaryPayId:'f58d63f6-e823-493a-acf4-226a9c4d21a1',parentBenePayId:'f5f04b9b-5711-44d5-b06e-fb525d269310',beneficiary:{topId:'4e86ab2e-3a2a-4914-a0b3-153439c4013b',businessId:'aead7de0-f2f3-46ce-a013-f83833b9ec0a',businessName:'Ward-Collier',},},{beneficiaryPayId:'17263490-9b2b-4b87-a638-cbdaf0cd9daa',parentBenePayId:'f5f04b9b-5711-44d5-b06e-fb525d269310',beneficiary:{topId:'751b8076-d7ca-4cca-922b-aabcc4b39845',businessId:'6ae1d6e1-9a3b-482b-9c2a-861b3bea0cd4',businessName:'Nikolaus Dickinson and Wiegand',},},{beneficiaryPayId:'71e36088-724f-4075-be14-5fdb37944447',parentBenePayId:'b1da8c12-cb0d-4b0e-8a30-75362dbf73b4',beneficiary:{topId:'a6c67099-9937-4daa-829f-9b91adfea9a1',businessId:'dbbb2e12-e50a-4905-93c1-29768b6ed74d',businessName:'Rath Group',},},{beneficiaryPayId:'d50f34c9-9576-4511-9c49-4fe1fc296a57',parentBenePayId:'b1da8c12-cb0d-4b0e-8a30-75362dbf73b4',beneficiary:{topId:'12e65313-943a-406a-9771-bd8485a35862',businessId:'70d44d44-f7bf-4fd3-a475-378be757d86f',businessName:'MacGyver Inc',},},],};

const getParent = (data, parentBenePayId) => {
  return data.payBeneficiaries.find(
    pBen => pBen.beneficiaryPayId === parentBenePayId
  );
};

let res = input.payBeneficiaries.map(ben => {
  let parent = getParent(input, ben.parentBenePayId);
  let output = {
    orgHierarchy: [ben.beneficiary.businessName],
  };
  if (parent) {
    output.orgHierarchy.splice(0, 0, parent.beneficiary.businessName);
    if (parent.parentBenePayId) {
      let grandParent = getParent(input, parent.parentBenePayId);
      if (grandParent) {
        output.orgHierarchy.splice(0, 0, grandParent.beneficiary.businessName);
      }
    }
  }
  return output;
});
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

This works for your example, i.e., considering 3 levels. But this example can be tweaked and extended for multiple levels of heirarchy.

Answer (score 0):

#### Approach:

You could use recursive call with base condition of parentId is empty

```js
const payBeneficiaryLookupById = payBeneficiaries.reduce(
  (acc, pb) => ({ ...acc, [pb.beneficiaryPayId]: pb }),
  {}
)

const getOrgHierarchy = (payBeneficiary, acc) => {
  if (!payBeneficiary.parentBenePayId) {
    return [payBeneficiary.beneficiary.businessName, ...acc]
  } else {
    return getOrgHierarchy(
      payBeneficiaryLookupById[payBeneficiary.parentBenePayId],
      [payBeneficiary.beneficiary.businessName, ...acc]
    )
  }
}

const res = payBeneficiaries.map((pb) => ({
  orgHierarchy: getOrgHierarchy(pb, []),
}))
```

---

#### Implementation:

```js
const { payBeneficiaries } = {
  payBeneficiaries: [
    {
      beneficiaryPayId: "c946c383-6a64-476a-b903-3bc8baaa716c",
      parentBenePayId: "",
      beneficiary: {
        topId: "06d5e9eb-7110-4c90-aa77-97b3d8ca2c9a",
        businessId: "15c58e7d-18dd-49e3-ad86-0bf3f6e5013a",
        businessName: "Royal NNJ p.l.c.",
      },
    },
    {
      beneficiaryPayId: "b1da8c12-cb0d-4b0e-8a30-75362dbf73b4",
      parentBenePayId: "c946c383-6a64-476a-b903-3bc8baaa716c",
      beneficiary: {
        topId: "d56eebf3-b97b-429c-ae09-e488d85169cf",
        businessId: "a52b0a2d-532b-4fd1-b667-c25691217e5e",
        businessName: "Hammes Macejkovic and Steuber",
      },
    },
    {
      beneficiaryPayId: "f5f04b9b-5711-44d5-b06e-fb525d269310",
      parentBenePayId: "c946c383-6a64-476a-b903-3bc8baaa716c",
      beneficiary: {
        topId: "96737c75-7a7f-4edc-a6b5-cb3149879a78",
        businessId: "4e3b061d-5706-45b4-925d-cab675c95d98",
        businessName: "Torphy-Osinski",
      },
    },
    {
      beneficiaryPayId: "2a027e32-ac76-48e4-9ab5-bec130211107",
      parentBenePayId: "c946c383-6a64-476a-b903-3bc8baaa716c",
      beneficiary: {
        topId: "0f9c1849-2c1d-42ae-bdb1-40d83d912171",
        businessId: "92ea79f3-ed3f-42e1-8f4c-9e1ccb3d746a",
        businessName: "Schinner Inc",
      },
    },
    {
      beneficiaryPayId: "d0ec2133-fb2f-4cf2-8d2b-3d8d9eed7d09",
      parentBenePayId: "f5f04b9b-5711-44d5-b06e-fb525d269310",
      beneficiary: {
        topId: "54c30c9f-a792-4659-adfc-b4287994cf1e",
        businessId: "e6b95c56-ca17-40a4-b5f7-3a0c9fa9b327",
        businessName: "Ferry-Donnelly",
      },
    },
    {
      beneficiaryPayId: "e0b87efe-1bd3-4584-b102-2210ab2bd8a7",
      parentBenePayId: "2a027e32-ac76-48e4-9ab5-bec130211107",
      beneficiary: {
        topId: "b934b36a-0ab5-4869-9220-3bfd90bfb956",
        businessId: "c47836bb-87e2-482b-bbf0-d42073c372c6",
        businessName: "Lueilwitz-Johns",
      },
    },
    {
      beneficiaryPayId: "f58d63f6-e823-493a-acf4-226a9c4d21a1",
      parentBenePayId: "f5f04b9b-5711-44d5-b06e-fb525d269310",
      beneficiary: {
        topId: "4e86ab2e-3a2a-4914-a0b3-153439c4013b",
        businessId: "aead7de0-f2f3-46ce-a013-f83833b9ec0a",
        businessName: "Ward-Collier",
      },
    },
    {
      beneficiaryPayId: "17263490-9b2b-4b87-a638-cbdaf0cd9daa",
      parentBenePayId: "f5f04b9b-5711-44d5-b06e-fb525d269310",
      beneficiary: {
        topId: "751b8076-d7ca-4cca-922b-aabcc4b39845",
        businessId: "6ae1d6e1-9a3b-482b-9c2a-861b3bea0cd4",
        businessName: "Nikolaus Dickinson and Wiegand",
      },
    },
    {
      beneficiaryPayId: "71e36088-724f-4075-be14-5fdb37944447",
      parentBenePayId: "b1da8c12-cb0d-4b0e-8a30-75362dbf73b4",
      beneficiary: {
        topId: "a6c67099-9937-4daa-829f-9b91adfea9a1",
        businessId: "dbbb2e12-e50a-4905-93c1-29768b6ed74d",
        businessName: "Rath Group",
      },
    },
    {
      beneficiaryPayId: "d50f34c9-9576-4511-9c49-4fe1fc296a57",
      parentBenePayId: "b1da8c12-cb0d-4b0e-8a30-75362dbf73b4",
      beneficiary: {
        topId: "12e65313-943a-406a-9771-bd8485a35862",
        businessId: "70d44d44-f7bf-4fd3-a475-378be757d86f",
        businessName: "MacGyver Inc",
      },
    },
  ],
}

const payBeneficiaryLookupById = payBeneficiaries.reduce(
  (acc, pb) => ({ ...acc, [pb.beneficiaryPayId]: pb }),
  {}
)

const getOrgHierarchy = (payBeneficiary, acc) => {
  if (!payBeneficiary.parentBenePayId) {
    return [payBeneficiary.beneficiary.businessName, ...acc]
  } else {
    return getOrgHierarchy(
      payBeneficiaryLookupById[payBeneficiary.parentBenePayId],
      [payBeneficiary.beneficiary.businessName, ...acc]
    )
  }
}

const res = payBeneficiaries.map((pb) => ({
  orgHierarchy: getOrgHierarchy(pb, []),
}))

console.log(res)
```